# Is it me or does this AWS Lambda developer guide make no sense?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to learn how to use AWS Lambda as I think it could be a great tool for some projects I want to do with my students. I followed the hello world tutorial without any problem and so moved on to the next tutorial which uses Python and S3: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html

After a bit of faffing I passed through stage 1 and on to stage 2. Almost straight away it seems to lose clarity. So I have to create a python file, fine. And then I have to connect and copy my file to a server - er what? I thought the point of Lambda was to not have to worry about servers and only worry about having code/functions.

Indeed the start of the tutorial says you need 2 buckets and a lambda function. So you can imagine that the sudden requirement to connect to a Linux server threw me completely. Have I missed something or is the tutorial a bit confusing?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm puzzled that you expect to use AWS _without putting your code on an AWS server_.

Comment: My understanding is that Lambda is serverless and therefore you can create functions without having to worry about setting up an EC2 server.

Answer (score 2):

Your confusion is justified, because AWS Lambda maybe doesn't have the prettiest solution for creating Python deployment packages.

In order for your Lambda function to work, it requires not only pure Python code, but the libraries it requires inside the deployment package (the zip).

The documentation you followed shows how to create this environment (Python code + libs) on an EC2 instance, but this is not mandatory.

If you want a simpler getting started guide see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/get-started-create-function.html

Good luck!

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying. Some python files, should they have no dependencies and only use functionality from the standard library, they can simply be set up as a Lambda function. But if they require something from another library - e.g. random, math etc, then they need to be packaged as a zip.

Can you therefore create the zip without doing it on an EC2 instance, I'd rather not have to worry about setting up another service.

Comment: No need for dedicated EC2, that's just an option they chose to show in that specific doc for some reason. See this for a more focused explanation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Comment: @RobertFlook just to be sure you're clear: *"I'd rather not have to worry about setting up another service"*  It's not really "another service." The EC2 instance is disposable.  You'll find it convenient down the road, because you can fire it up from the stock image, build and test in a clean environment, and discard it when done.